# Man in a retirement home with a virtual reality window

Tags: story-identification

The gist of the story is that an old man is put in a retirement home where his room features a VR ‘window’ that featured views of various scenic points in the world. The retiree argues with his children by saying it's not the real thing, his children argue and say it’s “better”. He escapes the home and catches a ride with someone who is illegally driving a car (all cars in this future are self-driving and modifying it to be human-driven is a crime). The car crashes, he goes to hospital, and his kids scold him for being a Luddite and eventually put him back in the retirement home.

It wasn’t in a kid’s SF anthology, as one of the other stories in the book featured pretty explicit lesbian intercourse, but I found it thought provoking as a kid and can't seem to find it now.